# Mirror the value of a text field in another one using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, text

I've been trying to make the following code work inside Bubble(.io).

I setup an HTML element **(sourceField)** that fetches data dynamically from the database:

```
<body>
    <div class="field-container">
        <div id="sourceField" class="invisible-text">
            [dynamic data from the database]
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, I have another HTML element **(outputField)** with some JavaScript code, which looks as follows:

```
<body>
    <div class="field-container">
        <div class="nohyphen oneline" id="outputField"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function updateText() {
        var sourceField = document.getElementById("sourceField");
        var outputField = document.getElementById("outputField");

        outputField.innerHTML = sourceField.innerHTML;
    }
</script>
```

I would like the **outputField** to display or mirror automatically and in real-time what's shown in the **sourceField**, without the user having to do anything. The value of the **outputField** is text-only and might change in short intervals.

I have tried to append

```
setInterval(updateText, 1000);
```

to the above JavaScript, but this causes an error.

Does anyone have an idea of what kind of function I could add to make this work?

Comment: In the onChange from the source, fill the target input with the same value

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Instead of interval your logic it's better to wrote it inside a callback which triggers after any database change

Comment: A `function` needs to be *called* to execute. You have only defined it. Attach an 'onchange' eventlistener to `#sourceField` that executes `function update()` or execute it after a database action. You have to decide what triggers the need for execution of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much!

The "setInterval" example works inside JSFiddle, but Bubble produces a "General Error". The "updateText" function doesn't produce an error but doesn't seem to work on JSFiddle nor Bubble. I also tried to append "document.getElementById("sourceField").onchange = updateText;" (as suggested above), but to no avail. At least I can't get a result on JSFiddle, nor does Bubble respond to that.

Comment: See the [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) API and [`Node.cloneNode()
`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by, upon loading the page, you call the `updateText()` which then updates the `outputField` every second by using the `setInterval`.

```
<body onload="updateText()"> <!-- call function on page load -->
    <div class="field-container">
        <div class="nohyphen oneline" id="outputField"></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function updateText() {
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById("outputField").innerHTML = document.getElementById("sourceField").innerHTML
        }, 1000); // 1000 == 1 second
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your effort. Unfortunately, I tried the "setInterval" before and it doesn't work with Bubble.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest using onChange but instead of using a div to host the dynamic data from database like this

```
    <div id="sourceField" class="invisible-text">
        [dynamic data from the database]
    </div>
```

you can put the them inside of a hidden input tag

```
    <input type="text" id="sourceField" class="invisible-text" value="[dynamic data from the database]" />
```

then this code should work well

```
   var sourceField = document.getElementById("sourceField");
   var outputField = document.getElementById("outputField");

   sourceField.addEventListener("change", function () {
      outputField.textContent =  this.textContent;
   });
```

Comment: Dear Ahmad, Thanks a lot for your solution and your time. I implemented it exactly as you specified, but couldn't manage to make it work. My guess is that Bubble somehow limits what's possible with Javascript.